# RECURSION in PYTHON to make all possible PERMUTATIONS without repeat

Tags: python, recursion, input, substring, permutation

I have written a code using recursion, which follows the following rules:

**RULES**
2 inputs:

- 1st input: define the length of the output, as an integer.
- 2nd input: write all elements that user want, as a string, that will
  be part of the output.

**With these two inputs, the program must do the following:**

- 1st. Find all possible substrings of the length entered in the input,
  [] * 1st input.
- 2nd. Form all the possible combinations with the elements entered in
  the 2nd input.
- 3rd. Print all possible combinations of length [] * 1st input, with
  the elements of the 2nd input, without repeating.

**CODE**
My code is as follows and it fails to give the length of the output:

```
def stringPermutations(string, prefix, permutation_list):
    if len(string) == 0:
        permutation_list.append(prefix)
    else:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            rem = string[0:i] + string[i + 1:]
            stringPermutations(rem, prefix + string[i], permutation_list)
    return sorted(list(dict.fromkeys(permutation_list)))
def main():
    n = int(input("write size: "))
    b = str(input("Write String: "))
    permutation_list = [] * n
    print(stringPermutations(b, " ", permutation_list))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EXAMPLE OF HOW SHOULD WORK:**

*Input*:

```
2
+x#
```

*Output*:

```
+x
+#
x+
x#
#+
#x
```

Could someone tell me why it doesn't work?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected code:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBboMwDL3nKyx6aLKyqV1vSPzDpB52qFBEVdNZAhOFoHX7eZYQEFuHL4nj5@f3YvPlPlo@DsMVK@icJb69oW16VzpquZOcTq8pGIsV3f251HVNnVOZAB9UAUOewz6mIR6RL6UxyFcZmdSIw7rDpaNqLRAQgy35hrJGlnG8UgsohMUG8knaeZ9RAbs5I389ZMUf@JozeIZDGohma78oihWbIs51veV/RSHC/zUlsZyE@r/wPpwkNr2Tyaclh9DRN2aQqMh1iQ5myPsIOY0KFtDjJN9zLuAJOFZtmLG@t0sKSbLiQwnhd6U1lw1qHVa21TpI13obtUcfYhhexe6@@QE)

```
def stringPermutations(n, string, prefix, permutation_list):
    if n == 0:
        permutation_list.append(prefix)
    else:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            rem = string[0:i] + string[i + 1:]
            stringPermutations(n - 1, rem, prefix + string[i], permutation_list)
    return permutation_list

def main():
    n = int(input("write size: "))
    b = str(input("Write String: "))
    permutation_list = [] * n
    print(stringPermutations(n, b, "", permutation_list))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Input:

```
2
+x#
```

Output:

```
['+x', '+#', 'x+', 'x#', '#+', '#x']
```